# java, android - breakout game - ball paddle bouncing

Tags: java, android, breakout

I made a simple breakout game for Android, and I have some problems when the ball reaches the bar (paddle). ball, bar are bitmaps. x,y are the positions of the ball, bx and by are the positions of the bar (paddle). speedX and speedY are the speed of the ball. this isn't a very nice solution. Where can I change the code?

```
if (y + ball.getHeight() >= c.getHeight()
                    - (10 + bar.getHeight())
                    && (x + ball.getWidth() / 2) >= bx - bar.getWidth() / 2
                    && (x + ball.getWidth() / 2) <= bx + bar.getWidth() / 2) {
                mp.start();

                xdirection = (((x + ball.getWidth()) / 2) - ((bx + bar
                        .getWidth())) / 2) / (bar.getWidth() / 2);

                speedY = -speedY;
                speedX = (speedX) * Math.abs(xdirection);
```

Comment: Do you have any issue?

Comment: yes, but the ball moves incorrect. if the ball reaches the left side of the paddle, the ball moves with right direction and not with left direction

Comment: so, invert the X (multiply by -1)...

Comment: little bit better, but after 30-40 play speedX will be 0 or really near to zero.

Comment: So you have to rethink your coordinate system. If minX = 0, then maxX must be as wide as the gamefield. If minX = -1 * (gameField.width / 2), then maxX has to be gameField.width / 2.